# Linux drive not being read anywhere

Tags: linux, partition, disk, manjaro

I installed Manjaro Linux on my new 128GB M.2 SSD. It was all working fine for a week or so. I was then deleting some large files (4+GB) from another 2TB HDD. Each of these deletions took about a minute, and my computer became very slow and laggy as it performed the deletions, which I was surprised by as it also has 8GB of RAM and a i3 CPU. As I deleted each file, they were put into my trash, which I would assume is stored on the Linux SSD - so these files were basically being transferred from the HDD to the SSD when I pressed "Move to trash". One by one, I deleted all 7 of these large files and after each one I emptied the trash (deleted the file from the Trash folder on the Linux SSD).

I then decided to reboot once all 7 files were completely deleted. Grub suddenly showed, on reboot, that there was no bootable drive. It wouldn't recognise my Manjaro Linux installation. I am now booted up into the bootable USB I used a week ago to install Manjaro from. My HDD is disconnected, and the SSD is still connected. The only drive/partition showing in Gparted and with `fdisk -l` is the USB.

Any idea as to what could be casuing this, or how I can resolve it? I have no problem with doing a full wipe and fresh install on the SSD - all of my important data is on the disconnected HDD.

**Edit:**

```
[manjaro@manjaro ~]$ sudo hdparm -I $(ls /dev/sd?)

/dev/sda:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

ATA device, with non-removable media
Standards:
        Likely used: 1
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       0       0
        heads           0       0
        sectors/track   0       0
        --
        Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:           0 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:           0 MBytes 
        cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
        IORDY not likely
        Cannot perform double-word IO
        R/W multiple sector transfer: not supported
        DMA: not supported
        PIO: pio0
```

**Edit 2:**

```
[manjaro@manjaro ~]$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0    10M  1 loop /run/miso/sfs/livefs
loop1    7:1    0 224.4M  1 loop /run/miso/sfs/mhwdfs
loop2    7:2    0   1.3G  1 loop /run/miso/sfs/desktopfs
loop3    7:3    0 371.8M  1 loop /run/miso/sfs/rootfs
sda      8:0    1  14.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    1  14.5G  0 part /run/miso/bootmnt
[manjaro@manjaro ~]$ blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="MJRO170R" UUID="7490-2820" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="18f73e82-01"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
[manjaro@manjaro ~]$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5904 (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V (rev 21)
3a:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fd (rev 78)
3b:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
3c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation Device f1a5 (rev 03)
```

It is an Intel 128GB PCIe M.2 SSD, so I believe it is the last device listed at address 3c:00.0.

I have also gone into BIOS and realised that the SSD is recognised and my exact model is listed under Devices > SATA > NVMe M.2 SSD.

**EDIT 3:**

[Output of dmesg on boot](http://pastebin.com/gjepJt6J)

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo hdparm -I $(ls /dev/sd?)`.  This will provide detailed info on all connected drives.

Comment: I hve posted the output. Keep in mind that I am currently running from a bootable USB. so this USB as well as my 128GB SSD should be recognised

Comment: That looks like you're only showing `/dev/sda`, which is probably your booted USB device.

Comment: I know, but my SSD is also connected, hence that it doesn't seem to be read from.anywhere

Comment: Ok, so I have opened up the BIOS, and my SSD is listed in the "devices" section Under SATA > M.2 NVMe SDD. So it is being recognised in the BIOS, but not anywhere when booted up

Comment: What does `dmesg` show after boot wrt. to the SATA controller? (Please don't `grep`, try to identify the relevant parts. If you can't make sense of it, put it all into a pastebin and edit question).

Comment: Oh, it's NVMe.  "The Linux NVMe driver is natively included in the kernel since version 3.3. NVMe devices should show up under /dev/nvme* " - Arch Linux wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_State_Drives/NVMe ... so try `ls /dev/nvme*` and if drives show up, give us the `sudo hdparm -I $(ls /dev/nvme???)`

Comment: @SchivesNothing is showing up for `le dev/nvme*`

Comment: @dirkt I have added the pastebin of `dmesg` to my post. THis command was run as soon as I booted into the bootable USB. I really don't know what I should be looking for or if it should be 800 lines long, but in lines 788-790, you can see some NVMe Controller timeouts and errors. Please let me know what you can find from this data.

Comment: Some users of the Nvidia Jetson TX1 had trouble with their Intel 600-series M.2 PCIe SSDs.  As it turns out, the drives were being throttled back to 2.5GT/s (version 1 speeds).  Their logs are *remarkably* similar to what you've provided us here, so just as a shot in the dark, try Nvidia vidyas's solution: completely disable active state power management at the defconfig level `CONFIG_PCIEASPM=n`.  Source: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/973034/jetson-tx1/-solved-problem-with-intel-600p-nvme-ssd/1

Comment: Their problems do seem very similar to mine. The only two, crucial, differences I see is that, firstly, I am running an Intel NUC, where all the parts are made by Intel, so it would be quite surprising if an Intel SSD wasn't compatible. Secondly, the fact that my SSD worked fine for a week certainly is very strange, unless an update of my system caused these speed throttling issues. Anyway, it definitely is worth a shot in the dark, but excuse my ignorance - how and where do I make this defconfig edit?

Comment: Bear in mind, I've never done this before (so take it with a truckload of salt).  I believe the procedure is to clone into your desired linux kernel version: either the sources provided by the distro (what I would recommend), or the kernel.org repo.  `cd` to the kernel source directory.  Edit `./drivers/pci/pcie/Kconfig`; under `config PCIEASPM` there is a line that says `default y`, change it to say `default n`.  Save & exit.  Issue the command `make defconfig` (this builds the `.config`), then `make` (to build the kernel).  After that, you'll have to find out how to make Manjaro use it.

Comment: You might want to try disabling ASPM at boot time by setting the kernel parameter `pcie_aspm=off` https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Power_Management_Guide/ASPM.html (should probably try this before building the kernel from scratch).  To set kernel parameters at boot time see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_parameters